# Set dropdown value in a Javascript bookmark, my code works with textfields only

Tags: javascript, html, web, drop-down-menu

At work we had a handy coworker who made a bookmark that auto-filled our ID in textfields on a webpage using javascript that worked wonders. However my company changed the textfields to a dropdown and it no longer works. I've been digging around for a while and I can't seem to find a solution that works. I have very little experience with javascript though. This is what the code was for the textfields:

```
javascript:{document.getElementById('ID').value=%12345%22;document.getElementById('vendor').value=%2212345%22;void(0)}
```

I'm guessing the problematic part is the ".value=%" part? Do I need to put something else for a dropdown list?

Comment: should %12 and %22 get decoded?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to `%12345%22` must be between quotations.

```js
javascript:{document.getElementById('ID').value='%12347%22';}
```

```html
<select id="ID">
  <option value="%12346%22">Masoud</option>
  <option value="%12347%22">Yoleaux</option>
  <option value="%12348%22">Test1</option>
  <option value="%12349%22">Test2</option>
</select>
```

If it is not your actual problem please provide more information.